# Azure Active Directory: assign user to an application from the gallery via Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'd need to automate the process of adding an application from the gallery (i.e. Trello), configuring it (i.e. password single sign on) and assign users to it.

Can this be done via Graph API?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 
You can automate adding Trello to an Azure AD directory by creating a servicePrincipal in the directory corresponding to the Trello application. The default SSO setting is password SSO. You can also assign users (and groups) using graph API. However the assigned users will need to configure the password that they will use with the application manually.

Add Trello to the directory (create a servicePrincipal):

- appId is the application id of the Trello application. The value is a4937c28-17cc-469b-b082-1d6124a402f3 in all tenants.

`HTTP POST https://graph.windows.net/7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe
f517e304dfa0/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.5
Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXO--snip--zvg
Content-Type : application/json
Content-Length : 58
{
    "appId":  "a4937c28-17cc-469b-b082-1d6124a402f3"
}
Query successfully executed.`

`odata.metadata                     : https://graph.windows.net/7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe-f517e304dfa0/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectorySer
                                     vices.ServicePrincipal/@Element
odata.type                         : Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ServicePrincipal
objectType                         : ServicePrincipal
objectId                           : 93c60e8e-74f9-4add-9ae2-dd9bc0d6edcd
deletionTimestamp                  :
accountEnabled                     : True
appDisplayName                     : Trello
appId                              : a4937c28-17cc-469b-b082-1d6124a402f3
appOwnerTenantId                   : 47df5bb7-e6bc-4256-afb0-dd8c8e3c1ce8
appRoleAssignmentRequired          : False
appRoles                           : {@{allowedMemberTypes=System.Object[]; description=msiam_access; displayName=msiam_access;
                                     id=fc60bc23-43df-4a60-baaa-f0b8694e0259; isEnabled=True; value=}}
displayName                        : Trello
errorUrl                           :
homepage                           : https://127.0.0.1:444/applications/default.aspx?metadata=trello|ISV9.3|primary|z
keyCredentials                     : {}
logoutUrl                          :
oauth2Permissions                  : {}
passwordCredentials                : {}
preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint :
publisherName                      : Active Directory Application Registry
replyUrls                          : {https://127.0.0.1:444/applications/default.aspx}
samlMetadataUrl                    :
servicePrincipalNames              : {a4937c28-17cc-469b-b082-1d6124a402f3, http://adapplicationregistry.onmicrosoft.com/trello/primary}
tags                               : {}`

Assign principal (user or group) to Trello:

- resourceId is the objectId of the Trello servicePrincipal that get created in the tenant in the previous command.
- id is the default role id of Trello App. The value is fc60bc23-43df-4a60-baaa-f0b8694e0259 in all tenants.
- principalId is the objectId of the principal (user or group) that is being assigned to the app.

`HTTP POST https://graph.windows.net/7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe-f517e304dfa0/users/de4b092e-1dd4-4d40-b74d-a2d7096c9495/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5
Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOi--snip--JKVBfk_Q
Content-Type : application/json
Content-Length : 176
{
    "id":  "fc60bc23-43df-4a60-baaa-f0b8694e0259",
    "principalId":  "de4b092e-1dd4-4d40-b74d-a2d7096c9495",
    "resourceId":  "93c60e8e-74f9-4add-9ae2-dd9bc0d6edcd"
}
Query successfully executed.`

`odata.metadata       : https://graph.windows.net/7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe-f517e304dfa0/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleA
                       ssignment/@Element
odata.type           : Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleAssignment
objectType           : AppRoleAssignment
objectId             : LglL3tQdQE23TaLXCWyUlVPgf9W8rhZBi1YqpnYOyMg
deletionTimestamp    :
creationTimestamp    : 2015-01-29T05:52:12.4851494Z
id                   : fc60bc23-43df-4a60-baaa-f0b8694e0259
principalDisplayName :
principalId          : de4b092e-1dd4-4d40-b74d-a2d7096c9495
principalType        : User
resourceDisplayName  : Trello
resourceId           : 93c60e8e-74f9-4add-9ae2-dd9bc0d6edcd`

The assigned user will see the app in their access panel (myapp.microsoft.com). They will need to update the credentials manually.

[image]

Comment: Sounds great, thanks, I'll test this. One question, you say "However the assigned users will need to configure the password that they will use with the application manually." that's really bad for us. Via Portal we can assign username & pw, there is no way to do this programmatically?

Comment: I'm trying to find out.