# Azure AD Graph API - Assign user to applications using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I found that Applications can be assigned to users in this answer but can't seem to figure out how to do this using C#.  Below is the JSON and the C# I'm trying.

[Azure Active Directory: assign user to an application from the gallery via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170075/azure-active-directory-assign-user-to-an-application-from-the-gallery-via-graph#new-answer)

```
Assign principal (user or group) to application:
•resourceId is the objectId of the servicePrincipal that get created in the tenant for the application
•id is the default role id of App.
•principalId is the objectId of the principal (user or group) that is being assigned to the app.

HTTP POST https://graph.windows.net/7fe877e6-a150-4992-bbfe-f517e304dfa0/users/de4b092e-1dd4-4d40-b74d-a2d7096c9495/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5
Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOi--snip--JKVBfk_Q
Content-Type : application/json
Content-Length : 176
{
"id":  "fc60bc23-43df-4a60-baaa-f0b8694e0259",
"principalId":  "de4b092e-1dd4-4d40-b74d-a2d7096c9495",
"resourceId":  "93c60e8e-74f9-4add-9ae2-dd9bc0d6edcd"
}
        AppRoleAssignment appAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment();
        appAssignment.Id = appRole.Id;
        appAssignment.PrincipalId = new Guid(retrievedUser.ObjectId);
        appAssignment.ResourceId = new Guid("aa9b2f6b-6528-4552-a202-2039ce86d95c");

        appAssignment.UpdateAsync();
```

Comment: Did you ever work out how to assign a user to an azure app in c#?

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution if you found it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late to the party BUT! Since the documentation is completly missing I had to do a lot of googling and trail & error.

The solution is to update the user like this:

```
var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment()
{
    ResourceId = Guid.Parse(principal.ObjectId),
    PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(user.ObjectId),
    Id = Guid.Parse(roleId)
};

user.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);
await user.UpdateAsync();
```